# Cannot get text value of a clicked link

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the **text value of a clicked link**, but all that keeps being displayed is the **ID** value.

I searched the web and believe I am using the correct method. I even tried one with "target.text".

Can someone please inform me what I have wrong with the following jsFiddle?

### HTML

```
<form name="form" id="form" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="startdate">
    <input type="text" id="enddate">
    <input type="hidden" id="id" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" id="idText" value="">
    <button type="submit" value "change" name="change">Change</button>
    <br> <a href="1">PALPRD</a>

    <br> <a href="3">PALTST</a>

    <br> <a href="2">EYEBAL</a>

    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" value "back" name="back">Back</button>
</form>
```

### JS

```
$('a').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#id").val(url);

    var text = $(this).text();
    $("#idText").text();

    //var hv = $('#id').val();
    var hv2 = $('#idText').val();

    //alert(hv);
    alert(hv2);

    $('#form').submit();
    return false;
});
```

Please feel free to edit the jsFiddle...

[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ect0cygt/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to load jquery in fiddle and needed to change

$("#idText").val(text);

```js
 $('a').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();

   var url = $(this).attr('href');
   $("#id").val(url);

   var text = $(this).text();
   $("#idText").val(text);


   $('#form').submit();
   return false;
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form" id="form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="startdate">
  <input type="text" id="enddate">
  <input type="hidden" id="id" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" id="idText" value="">
  <button type="submit" value "change" name="change">Change</button>
  <br> <a href="1">PALPRD</a>

  <br> <a href="3">PALTST</a>

  <br> <a href="2">EYEBAL</a>

  <br>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" value "back" name="back">Back</button>
</form>
```

and here is your clean [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nil4you/ect0cygt/8/)

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy:

http://jsfiddle.net/nn09jast/

You have to choose jQuery and remove the script tags

Like this:

```
$('a').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).html());
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make few changes in this line:

```
var text = $(this).text();
$("#idText").val(text); // set text value to hidden field with val() instead of text()
```

As hidden input fields are form level elements and their values can be determined with `.val()`

see [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element) reference for more detail

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ect0cygt/6/)

Answer (score 0):

One small change and it works: you wanted, but did not, put the `text` variable as an argument of `text()` function of the hidden input `#idText`, which in addition should be `val(text)`:

```
$('a').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#id").val(url);
    var text = $(this).text();
    $("#idText").val(text);// only this line is changed
    //var hv = $('#id').val();
    var hv2 = $('#idText').val();
    //alert(hv);
    alert(hv2);
    //$('#form').submit();
    return false;
});
```